# Modal refactor over some common elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

These code works fine, but is repeating the same over and over, needs to refact.

The elements presented on page are Title and Description of all Modal. Rest 
of functionality is the same. Css is default bootstrap, it can be the same
whithout any important change.

I added another Help button on the side of each primary button, to help
search some information about how to find the documentation on every element
inside the Modals. Is no needed to focus on that at the moment.

Lorem ipsum text, can be placed on the respective container to complete
the description, and title, feel free to do it by your own.

To test the code, link Bootstrap 4.0 js files on the page.

So some guide to refact here, will be apreciated. Thank you very much.

```
<!-- DESCRIPTION & HELP BUTTONS-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-1" data-whatever="1. First Content">Title 1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle">?<i></i></button>
        </a></li>
</br>
        <li><a href="#">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-2" data-whatever="2. First Content">Title 2</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle">?<i></i></button>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END DESCRIPTION & HELP BUTTONS-->


<!-- MODAL's BODY DESCRIPTION -->
<div class="modal fade" id="example-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Title 1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text Description 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go to content</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- END MODAL's BODY DESCRIPTION-->

<!-- MODAL's BODY DESCRIPTION -->
<div class="modal fade" id="example-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Title 2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text Description 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go to content</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL's BODY DESCRIPTION-->

$('#example-1').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  } // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body p').text(recipient)
})

$('#example-2').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  } // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body p').text(recipient)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a single modal in which the information can be replaced according to the button that clicked it. To take care of a longer text for modal body part, I added a  that contains the relevant text along with the button in the same li but keeping the same hidden.  So on click of the modal lonk all the relevant values can be replaced using jquery like this.

```
       <!-- DESCRIPTION & HELP BUTTONS-->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-1" data-whatever="1. First Content">Title 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle" title="Information regarding first modal or...">?<i></i></button>
            <div id="1content" style="visibility: hidden;"> <p>Some text Description 1</p></div> 
    </a></li>

    <li><a href="#">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-1" data-whatever="2. Second Content">Title 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle" title="Information regarding second modal or...">?<i></i></button>
        <div id="2content" style="visibility: hidden;"> <p>Some text Description 2</p></div> 
    </a></li>
</ul>

<!-- END DESCRIPTION & HELP BUTTONS-->


<!-- MODAL's BODY DESCRIPTION -->
<div class="modal fade" id="example-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Title 1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p></p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go to content</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- END MODAL's BODY DESCRIPTION-->


<script>

$('a[data-toggle=modal], button[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {
  var button = $(this); // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = $(this).attr("data-whatever");

  var modal = $("#example-1");
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient);

  var div = $( "div" );
  // if last() is not used, then it brings that information button's ? as well
  var bodyText = $(this).siblings(div).last().text();
  modal.find('.modal-body p').text(bodyText);

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, for the response. But is not what i'm searching for.